# AWS Assume role for group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to assign an assume role to a group, then by user membership to the group users would be able to perform the necessary actions. So far I have the following:

1. An application user assigned to a group
2. This group has a role assigned to it with an assume role policy attached:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn::::role/test"
      }
    ]
  }
```

3. The referenced role (test) then has a policy attached to it with the necessary kms permissions

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "$kms-key-arn"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I test through aws-encryption-cli it says my user is not authorized to perform: kms:GenerateDataKey on resource:$ARN

My question is what else is needed so that my group can allow members to assume a role that has necessary permissions. This is all in the same AWS account.

Comment: Are you actually assumeing the role? From you description it does not seem that you are calling `aws sts assume-role` anywhere?

Comment: What is `$kms-key-arn`? Also, did you specify the full ARN for `arn::::role/test`? Did your code call `AssumeRole()` and then use the returned temporary credentials for calling `GenerateDataKey()`?

Comment: I have sts assume role in the group, not in the user. I figured the group would be able to pass this permission to the user. Does the user permission need to have sts assume role also ?